# How to scroll to top before going to a different page, when a user clicks a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I'm trying to create smooth page transitions on my website, so that a user doesn't feel the "page load" when he/she clicks a link to a different page. Two examples of what I want are [minimalissimo.com](http://minimalissimo.com/2015/04/rooms/) and [defringe.com](http://defringe.com/article/vindo). When you click a link to a different article on any page of these sites, the page animates a scroll to top before the next page starts loading.

So far I have the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $back_to_top = $('.link-to-article');

  $back_to_top.on('click', function(){
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},260);
  });

});
```

The above code doesn't work, no scroll occurs when you click a link with that class; however, if I use prevent default then the page does scroll to top but of course the next page doesn't open as the link is disabled with preventDefault.

Please let me know if you can help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that you will need to use `preventDefault`, but you will also need to manually redirect once the animation is complete:

```
$back_to_top.on('click', function(){
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   $(document.body).animate({scrollTop:0}, 260, function() {
      window.location.href = href;
   });
   return false;
});
```

Comment: I copied your code and it worked perfectly, even without adding `preventDefault`. However, I'm just concerned if there is any risk in using `window.location.href` to make the links work. Do I need to worry about links not working if someone has disabled javascript, or using an old browser or something? Thanks!

Comment: @SameerZahidd: No, you will still have graceful degradation, as the click won't be intercepted at all if javascript is not enabled. Right-click "open in new tab" etc still works since the address is specified in `href` (but that won't initiate the scroll). What you would lose with this approach is `target` of the original link. If that is important to you, you might try catching only the first click, using [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/), and then call `click` manually at the end of that event. But if you're not relying on `target`, I'd say the above solution is neater.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, and no the target is not important to me. I'l just use what you've shown above. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SameerZahidd: `return false` is functionally equivalent of `preventDefault` in this example; that is why the code works. An important distinction between the two is that `return false` has to be the last thing you do, for obvious reasons, while `preventDefault` can be called immediately. If your code should throw an exception before `return false` is reached, the click handler will stop executing, and `return false` will not be called, so the browser will follow the link (which is probably what you want).

Comment: Other times, `preventDefault` may be preferable for the exact same reason - because you *want* the default action to be prevented even in the case of an exception. Of course you could achieve the same thing by making `preventDefault` the last statement in the listener.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $back_to_top = $('.link-to-article');

    $back_to_top.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 260, function() {
            window.location.href = $this.attr('href');
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```